# ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundling and Minification

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I've been trying to get minification to work when in non-debug mode, but for some reason when I include `<compilation debug="false" />` in my Web.config it doesn't work.

However when I use `BundleTable.Enableoptimizations = true`, it seems to be working fine.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: `BundleTable.Enableoptimizations = true` is what makes it work in debug mode. If you remove that line, and it stops working (no bundling, etc), then you aren't in non-debug mode.

Comment: So (as stated below) <compilation debug="false"/> in web.config is completely irrelevant?

Comment: No... that should do it. Works fine for me.

Comment: Exactly why I posted the question. It's quite bizarre why it's not working.

Anything I could try out to find out?

I prefer having everything in web.config instead of throwing options here and there and having to hunt them down

Answer (score 3):

By default, it's disabled if you build in `debug` mode. but if you want to enable it in `release` mode but disable it in `debug` mode. In your bundle config, you can enable it by default and turn it off only in debug mode with c# `debug` directive.

```
BundleTable.Enableoptimizations = true

#if DEBUG
    BundleTable.Enableoptimizations = false
#endif
```

Comment: So <compilation debug="false"/> essentially does nothing?

I tried both building in debug and release, but it didnt seem to affect either

Comment: Correct, if your project is Web Application project. For Web Site projects, I'm not sure. What is the project type?

Comment: Not quite sure. ASP.NET MVC 4 -> Basic.. But I am assuming it is a Web Application, yes.